# Ubuntu Disk Management

Tags: partitioning, gparted, swap

So, I notice when I open up "Disks", that it is showing 3 partitions on my main drive.

1 is the system, 1 is the swap, but the other is simply labeled as "Extended Partition"

So what I'm wondering is #1, is this "Extended Partition" really necessary? (what's it do?), and #2 can I get rid of it, and resize my Swap partition (or resize my main partition to incorporate the extra 16G)

See screenshot... and please note, this is an SSD (blue = the "Extended Partition")

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is this "Extended Partition" really necessary? (what's it do?)

Extended partition is just like a container which holds all the logical partitions.

> can I get rid of it?

First you have to delete all the partitions which resides inside the extended partition inorder to  delete the extended partition.

If you want to increase the size of your root partition then decrease the swap space, get the shrinked space out of the extended partition and add it to the root partition.

Comment: But what partitions reside in it?  104G partition?

Comment: 16 GB swap partition.

Comment: getin [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11833/room-for-avinash-raj-and-whoever-wants-to-make-company) if you have any doubts in resizing.

Comment: I'm in... appreciate i